# iPhone Flickr group pool uploader

Tags: iphone, upload, camera, flickr

I'm trying to write an app that allows the user to take a photo, then upload it to a flickr group pool. Does anyone have any sample code that does this or can point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not a site where you can just ask for someone else to write your code for you.  I would suggest getting more specific with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by learning:

1. How to take a photo from the camera
   within your app
2. How to save said photo on the device
3. How to integrate the Flickr API in
   objective-c
4. How to use said API to upload the
   photo

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather unspecific. The Flickr API is [well documented](http://www.flickr.com/services/api/). You will have to use `NSURLConnection` to call the appropriate API methods.